# Boost.Spirit(2) Lex: strip_comments_lexer.cpp - not work?

Tags: boost-spirit, boost-spirit-lex

boost_1_47_0/libs/spirit/example/lex/strip_comments_lexer.cpp
Not strip C-style comments.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because is was broken :-P. It is fixed now in Boost SVN trunk (rev. [73620]). Thanks!